# spring boot could not find bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I'm trying make simply web portal, but when i try to build code by

> mvn clean install -X

I got error code

> Description:
>   Field userRepository in com.kapjee.dziennik.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.kapjee.dziennik.service.UserRepository' that could not be found.
>   Action:
>   Consider defining a bean of type 'com.kapjee.dziennik.service.UserRepository' in your configuration.

Below give you a tree of project.

[Tree of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkXrm.png)

UserDetailsServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
UsernameNotFoundException {

 User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
   if (user != null) {
      Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
      grantedAuthorities.add(new 
      SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().toString()));
      return new 
      org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
      user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
  } else {
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User was not found!");
  }

 }

}
```

This is UerService

```
@Service
public interface UserService {

  void save(User user);

  User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

And UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends  JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

In Main class i share all packaes

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.kapjee.dziennik"})
@EntityScan("com.kapjee.dziennik.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.kapjee.dziennik.model")
```

Comment: Don't you miss a `@Repository` on `UserRepository`?

Comment: @RC. this is not necessary

Comment: can you share your package setup

Comment: Even when i added @Repository on UserRepository, it is not working same error

Comment: @AmerQarabsa yes, i share packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.kapjee.dziennik.model")
```

I see you specified the jpa repositories in your model package, you need to include the package that contains the repositories also , so if your repositories under package com.kapjee.dziennik.repository just go a level back

```
 @EnableJpaRepositories("com.kapjee.dziennik")
```

Comment: @artist if this solves your issue please feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: But if i change one thing in view using thymeleaf, it's still the same error ;/

Comment: try to add @ComponentScan with your base package also

Comment: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.kapjee.dziennik"})`

Like this ?

Comment: yes, so when exactly do you see this error? not on the startup right?

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.kapjee.dziennik"})
@EntityScan("com.kapjee.dziennik.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.kapjee.dziennik")`

Comment: @artist when do you see the error? on the startup? can you share the full exception

Comment: this is what i've got in MAIN class

Comment: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.kapjee.dziennik.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.kapjee.dziennik.service.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.kapjee.dziennik.service.UserRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: In Eclipse, when i try to startup application, and in console when i'm trying build using maven command `mvn clean install`

Comment: remove all the annotations and keep @SpringBootApplication dn component scan

Comment: but now it's very weird stuff in eclipse its error but in console build end by BUILD SUCCESS
xD

Comment: try to restart eclipse

Comment: i'm trying to, and also trying maven update project and nothing

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `EnableJpaRepositories` is importing wrong package. I'm guessing the `UserRepository` is not in the `model` package. Use the type-safe attribute `basePackageClasses` instead of `basePackages`.
`@ComponentScan` and `EntityScan` are redundant in your case. I'm sorry to say, but it appears you put together some code with band-aid and glue without real understanding of what you're doing.

Comment: there is a link to Tree of project, there you can see where exacly is which file

Comment: ang it should look like this ? 

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.kapjee.dziennik"}, basePackageClasses = com.kapjee.dziennik.service.UserRepository.class)`

Comment: @artist `SpringBootApplication` is a meta annotation that already includes `ComponentScan`. Use your IDE for what it's worth.